# Use MASS::stepAIC in purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, glm, purrr

I try to apply the MASS::stepAIC() function to a list of models. I can't figure out how this works using purrr::map().

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

# Define function
cyl_fn <- function(df1){
     glm(cyl ~ drat + gear + carb, family = "poisson", data = df1)
}

# Nest data frame by vs
nested_cyl <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(vs) %>%
    tidyr::nest() 

# Fit model 
test <- nested_cyl %>%
    mutate(model_cyl = map(data, cyl_fn)) %>%
    mutate(model_cyl_aic = map(model_cyl, stepAIC))
```

This yields the following error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'df1' not found
```

What is the way to use the stepAIC function in the map function?

Comment: Looks like `stepAIC()` is having a hard time with how the model call/dataset are stored in the model output when using a function.  You can force things if you do the `stepAIC()` and model fitting in one step (without your `cyl_fn()`).  For example, this works for me: `nested_cyl %>% mutate(model_cyl = map(data, ~stepAIC(glm(cyl ~ drat + gear + carb, family = "poisson", data = .x))))`

Comment: Some quick debugging: run the block that assigns `test` without the second `mutate` call. Look at `test$model_cyl[[1]]` to see one of the model objects. Call `stepAIC` on that object—you get an error because there's no reference to the data frame the model was trained on. The [many models](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) chapter of R for Data Science might help